# How do I fix mismatched return types with a custom Error enum?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I've been running into the following error with mismatched types.  Currently using a custom Error enum to hold errors from various crates as shown in `error.rs` below and I'm trying to use it for my main function's return type.  How can I convert the error so that there aren't mismatched types?

#### Error message

```sh
→ cargo build
   Compiling dphoto v0.1.0 (/home/drk/Documents/github/dphoto)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:1
   |
10 | #[actix_rt::main]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `error::Error`, found struct `std::io::Error`
11 | async fn main() -> Result<()> {
   |                    ---------- expected `std::result::Result<(), error::Error>` because of return type
   |
   = note: expected type `std::result::Result<_, error::Error>`
              found type `std::result::Result<_, std::io::Error>`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `dphoto`.
```

#### Build info and dependencies

```sh
→ rustc --version
rustc 1.39.0 (4560ea788 2019-11-04)
```

#### main.rs

```rust
use actix_files as fs;
use actix_web::{middleware, App, HttpServer};

mod api;
mod error;
mod resizer;
use api::{album, image};
use error::Result;

#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    std::env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "actix_web=info");
    env_logger::init();

    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            // enable logger
            .wrap(middleware::Logger::default())
            .service(
                // static files
                fs::Files::new("/static", "./static/").show_files_listing(),
            )
            .service(album)
            .service(image)
    })
    .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
    .start()
    .await
}
```

#### error.rs

```rust
...

/// Common result type
pub type Result<T> = StdResult<T, Error>;

/// Common error type to hold errors from other crates
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Error {
    /// A `image` crate error
    Image(ImageError),
    /// A `std::io` crate error
    Io(IoError),
}

impl From<IoError> for Error {
    fn from(err: IoError) -> Error {
        Error::Io(err)
    }
}

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since starting the `HttpServer` responds with `Result<(), io::error::Error>`, the error needs to be converted into the custom `error::Error` enum.  This can be done by using the `?` operator then wrapping it again in an `Ok()`, so `Ok(HttpServer ... .start().await?)`.

Or, a cleaner way (imo) convert the error with `.map_err(Into::into)`.

`.map_err()` doesn't need to be used for the `.bind()` call as the `?` operator will convert the error.

```rust
#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    std::env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "actix_web=info");
    env_logger::init();

    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            // enable logger
            .wrap(middleware::Logger::default())
            .service(
                // static files
                fs::Files::new("/static", "./static/").show_files_listing(),
            )
            .service(album)
            .service(image)
    })
    .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
    .start()
    .await
    .map_err(Into::into)
}
```